# What is this minifig and is it from Atlantis?

Tags: minifigure-identification

[image: minifig]
Saw this on Facebook, what is this minifig?

Some people say it is from Atlantis but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This minifig is indeed from Atlantis, it is a [Atlantis Manta Warrior](http://brickset.com/minifigs/atl003/Atlantis-Manta-Warrior)

[image: Atlantis Manta Warrior]

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed the manta warrior. It is one of the several undersea warriors in the theme, although it's discontinued.